# Appartment Rent in a monthly budget

Tags: budget, rent

Good day;

I'm making a Monthly budget to keep track of where I spend my paychecks. I stumbled upon the **rent** part; would that be considered a **debt**? Since it's basically something that I "accept" I'll be paying for the next 12 months, each month, in accordance to the lease?

Comment: @DStanley Aah yes, it appears to be already answered there, thank you.

Comment: I think it is a different question; the other one is about a "financial assessment", this one about personal budgeting. And for personal budgeting, it is definitely cost (fix cost, to be precise).